# Azure Devops automated test results incoherent with powershell test results using the same data

Tags: powershell, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, automated-tests

I'm currently trying to integrate automatic test execution on the deployment process using Azure Devops but it's causing me an issue where some tests don't run properly.

The application I'm testing has a log-in page and I've set up a couple of tests to see if it opened properly. These ones run smoothly, but the ones that require going through the login process do not.

I've set up some snapshots amidst the process and the result was that I was getting an error on the last step of logging in. I've checked the application logs and the result I got was that no credentials were sent through the request which I found odd since they were displayed on the snapshots.

All the data being inserted was correct, I've checked the endpoints and settings on the agent that was running them and everything seemed fine.

I tried then to run the automated tests through powershell command directly on the same agent and all of them passed with no issue whatsoever.

I've tried changing my task to a powershell command but it still gives me an error.

I have no idea where my issue could be or where I should be even able to start looking for the problem, as clearly it seems that the problem is on the azure devops task but everything seems fine with it, I've tinkered around with the settings a bit but none of them seemed to have any impact on the results I was getting.

I'm using version 2 of the vstest task and am targetting the test assembly that was deployed to the agent. Any idea on what I could be missing or pointers on how to find the solution?

Comment: Just wanted to check in after the weekend what the status on this issue was? Does the agent with interaction mode could help you achieve your expection?

Comment: The agent was already set to interaction mode, the issue was with my vstest version as installing a different one did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These ones run smoothly, but the ones that require going through the
>   login process do not

Based on this description, it seems that it will open a new window automatically by the task.

If I'm right, and your test will open a window to login with your private-hosted agent. At this time, the mode of your private-hosted agent must be in [`interactive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#interactive-or-service) which it can allow auto-logon enabled.

Just check this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=azure-devops#decide-how-you-will-deploy-and-test-your-app) for more detail information.